# OPENCART php Created new controller query method and view getting empty lines

Tags: php, mysql, twig, opencart

I am creating a custom page where I will show all downloadable data from manufacturers. So I created new table where I store the path for files and foreign key to manufacturer table.
My query looks like this:

```
public function getManufacturersDownloads(){
    $sql = "SELECT " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer.name, " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer.manufacturer_id, " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer_downloads.path FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer INNER JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer_downloads ON " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer_downloads.manufacturer_id = " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer.manufacturer_id";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $query->rows;
}
```

My controller for getting that data looks like this:

```
$katalogai = $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getManufacturersDownloads();

foreach($katalogai as $katalogas){
    //   $data['downloads']['path'] = $katalogas['path'];
    //   $data['downloads']['name'] = $katalogas['name'];
    //   $data['downloads']['manufacturer_id'] = $katalogas['manufacturer_id'];

    $data['downloads'][] = array(
        'path' => $katalogas['path'],
        'name' => $katalogas['name'],
        'manufacturer_id' => $katalogas['manufacturer_id']
    );  
}
```

My view file where I want to display results looks like this:

```
<ul>
     {% for download in downloads %}
         <li>{{download.path}}</li>
         {#<li>{{download.manufacturer_id}}</li>#}
         {#<li>{{download.name}}</li>#}
     {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I get 20 empty lines in the view, I have 20 manufacturers, so it fetches some data maybe or its null, I don't know what i did wrong.

On phpmyadmin the query returns data, I've tested it.

Comment: You're not fetching any real data from the manufacturers, only the amount of records...

Comment: Changed data assignment and it fixed the problem

Comment: {% for download in downloads.downloads %}